# QLinkedList size() function

Tags: c++, qt, linked-list

I am wondering does the size() function returns an internal stored variable (which gives the size of the linked list) or does it iterates over the list and counts the nb of elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just returns the stored number of items. The implementation is the following:

```
 inline int size() const { return d->size; }
```

Answer (score 2):

From the source: `inline int size() const { return d->size; }`

In other words, it's stored as a variable so its time complexity is O(1)

See http://cep.xor.aps.anl.gov/software/qt4-x11-4.2.2-browser/d7/df0/src_2corelib_2tools_2qlinkedlist_8h-source.html for more information, the function you're looking for is on line 71.

Answer (score 1):

As far as it is written in the [source code](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/tools/qlinkedlist.h#line96), it just returns internal varibale.

Also you should understand that it is implementation detail and can be changed in future versions.